# Moment and maximum likelihood estimator of a parameter of a distribution

Tags: calculus, probability, expected-value, maximum-likelihood

**Question:** Suppose $n$ samples are taken from the following distribution:

### $f(x)=\frac{x}{\beta} e^{-x^{2} /(2 \beta)}$

where $x$ and $\beta$ are positive. $E(X_i^{2}) = 2\beta$ and $E(X_i) = \sqrt{\frac{\beta \pi}{2}}$, now we are asked to find moment estimator and maximum likelihood estimator for $\beta$.

Here are my approaches that the results of which for some reason are not consistent between the two approaches (My maximum likelihood estimator is the negative of the moment estimator!):

Moment estimator method:

$E[x]=\bar{x}
\rightarrow \sqrt{\frac{\beta \pi}{2}}=\bar{x} \rightarrow \frac{\beta \pi}{2}=\bar{x}^{2} \rightarrow \beta=2 \bar{x}^{2} / \pi$

Maximum likelihood method:

$L(\beta)=\prod_{i=1}^{n} f\left(x_{i} ; \beta\right)=\prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{x_{i}}{\beta} e^{-x_{i}^{2}/(2 \beta)}$

$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ =\beta^{-n}\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}\right) \exp \left(\frac{-\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}^{2}}{2 \beta}\right)$

$\operatorname{lag} L(\beta)=-n \log \beta+\sum_{i=1}^{n} \log x_{i}-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}^{2}}{2 \beta}$

$\frac{d}{d \beta} \log L(\beta)=\frac{-n}{\beta}+\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}^{2}}{2 \beta^{2}}=0$

$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}^{2}}{2 \beta}=n \rightarrow \beta=\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}^{2}}{n} = \frac{E(X_i^{2})}{2}$

$E(X_i^{2}) = Var(X_i) - E(X_i)^2 = 2\beta - \frac{\beta \pi}{2} - \bar{X}^2$

Hence $\beta=-2 \bar{x}^{2} / \pi$

Can't find the problem of my solutions, can anyone help?

Comment: $\frac1n\sum x_i^2\ne E[X_i^2]$

Comment: Thanks @ShubhamJohri . Do you know the correct answer for beta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method of moments estimator is correct.  Clearly, your maximum likelihood calculation cannot be correct.

The likelihood function for a sample $\boldsymbol x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ is proportional to $$\mathcal L(\beta \mid \boldsymbol x) \propto \beta^{-n} \exp \left(- \frac{1}{2\beta} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \right)$$ so that the log-likelihood is $$\ell(\beta \mid \boldsymbol x) = -n \log \beta - \frac{n \overline{x^2}}{2\beta} ,$$ where $\overline{x^2}$ is the sample second moment; i.e., the mean of the square of the sample.  Consequently we search for critical points satisfying $$0 = \frac{\partial \ell}{\partial \beta} = -\frac{1}{\beta} + \frac{\overline{x^2}}{2\beta^2},$$ hence $$\hat \beta = \frac{\overline{x^2}}{2}.$$  This of course is different than the method of moments estimator, but they are both asymptotically consistent.